# How to get nearest locations based on current location in java

Tags: java, google-maps

Actually I have latitude and longitude saved in the database for all the ATMs . In current scenario I am getting the latitude and longitude from android side to server side. But i am getting difficulties while sending him the nearby ATMs based on latitude and longitude. Please suggest me the good approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the SQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate. It calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance value is less than 25, orders the whole query by distance, and limits it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.

```html
Table Structure :

id | name | address | lat | lng
```

NOTE - Here latitude = 28 & longitude = -116. So you just pass your own.

```html
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(28) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-116) ) + sin( radians(28) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

You can read about this formula here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: It is not working for me . I am using following query                      
SELECT atmid, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(28) ) * cos( radians( 12.8552 ) ) * cos( radians( 77.5878 ) - radians(-116) ) 
+ sin( radians(28) ) * sin( radians( 12.8552 ) ) ) )
 AS distance FROM ATMInfo HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

Comment: SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * 
sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM your_table_name HAVING
distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;